# Microservices "JOINS"

Tags: microservices

Let's say we want to create the app with microservices.

We have some page where we display some items (products).

These products have multiple joins(categories, tags, users, and so on).

If users, categories data are within another services, how can we manage and filter the results?

For example in SQL you create 3,4 joins and get.

With microservices - I have to filter the categories, then filter tags and then products - this could be 10 time slower than the speed of the SQL query.

Also if I have table "products_categories" which set categories for each product which service is responsible for that? Product service or Category service ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In Microservices architecture there are two ways to deal with it.

1. The API composition pattern— This is the simplest approach and should be used whenever possible. It works by making clients of the services that own the data responsible for invoking the services and combining the results.
2. The Command query responsibility segregation (CQRS) pattern— This is more powerful than the API composition pattern, but it’s also more complex. It maintains one or more view databases whose sole purpose is to support queries.

I will prefer to use CQRS, Define a view database, which is a read-only replica  to support specifically that query. The rest of the services keeps the replica up to date by subscribing to (create, update, insert)events published by the data owner services.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very standard problem whenever any micro-service is built.. People just always feel micro-service is the solution for everything which is not true.

Solution to this problem is designing better. Designing so that there is a balance between performance and redundancy of data. Higher performance ( lower latency numbers ) means more duplicacy of data across different databases of microservice. You should not target to achieve performance as good as SQL Joins ; but also do not duplicate data too much. A balance is needed..

Most importantly, dividing the requirement into right set of micro-services is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created a "microservice" per database table. Those are not microservices, those are just HTTP-based CRUD interfaces to your database.

First, know why you need microservices. (Is there an actual reason?) Second, you have to create microservices that encompass at least one full (business) functionality for your software. Meaning it doesn't need other services to do it.

If you need a table that needs data from multiple microservices, you by definition made wrong microservices. If a microservice can't provide it's own UI without the help of other services, it doesn't fully contain it's own functionality.

Comment: I agree, but this means that the whole database should be one service because any table could depend on other table recursive. So how will i create PaymentsService if payment depends on users, products,categories.

Comment: The database you have today (products, users, etc.) can not really be split, as you pointed out. You have to redesign you data too. A typical split for an online shop is for example: the "search" service, where all the text and images of a product is for example. The "ordering", where skus, prices and such live. A "logistics" where all the user addresses, etc are. Basically you have to split you "monolithic" data tables too. Obviously this all depends heavily on your use-case, so I don't know what would be appropriate for your project.

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from having multiple services for reading / writing to the same database / table? For example:

- One service to write to `categories`
- One service to write to `tags`
- One service to write to `products`

You could then write another service to read from all three of these services, however, this might not be at a HTTP level, instead you could read from the same `database` within your `read` service and leverage the power of `SQL`.

The service that reads could encompass your `join` logic which would mean you wouldn't need to consume the other services around it.

Comment: By definition each service should have separate database they say - if not it's not really a microservice.

Comment: Who defines that? Why should each microservice have separate databases? I've worked on systems that talk to the same database within SOA beforehand.

Comment: https://plainoldobjects.com/2015/09/02/does-each-microservice-really-need-its-own-database-2. If 2 microservices access the same database it's not really a "microservice" but different module or similar. Its not encapsulated within the service.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I can't see that quote anywhere, although it's suggested multiple data stores should be used. Instead of using SQL, have you thought about flattening the data and storing it withing something like Elasticsearch or Solr?

Comment: You also don't _need_ one database per service. You could have multiple tables within one database that each service maintains. This is my opinion though.